# how to use text of one cell to make a function in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one cell i want to put a file path in, say [C:\users\me\desktop\abc.xlsm]
In another cell reference that text and add on SHEET'$A1 to the end so it references the first cell and then takes the filepath and pulls what is on column A row 1.
I want to do it this way so I can just add in file paths and have the rest of the information auto pull from the file path.
I can't seem to do this.

Comment: You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to dynamically access a cell in an external workbook, using the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\PathToFile\[FileName.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1")
```

**However,** there's one significant drawback using this method: the external file must be open, otherwise it will return a `#REF!` error.

Here is an example with the file open:

[image]

And with the file closed:

[image]

---

More information on this answer: [INDIRECT gives a #REF! error for reference to external workbook where making a direct reference with an equal sign works. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/535871/indirect-gives-a-ref-error-for-reference-to-external-workbook-where-making-a-d#535924)